# Where is the AMPathPopUpButton class declared?

Tags: cocoa, path, controls, declaration, automator

I stumbled upon the AMPathPopUpButton control in the Interface Builder, but every time I try to use it, the compiler notified me

> Use of undeclared type 'AMPathPopUpButton'.

According to some search, it should be in the Automator framework. But after I import the framework, I still have no luck.

I suspect that this control may have been deprecated, however, it is still available in Interface Builder, and I couldn't find any information about its retirement.

Is it still usable in code? If yes, what should I import or do?

Comment: You're using Cocoa? AppleScriptKit does not play nice with Cocoa.

Comment: Yes, I am using Cocoa. What do you mean by "does not play nice"? Is it that this control was not designed for Cocoa? Then why is it shyly available in the Interface Builder?

Comment: Interface Builder also works with AppleScript Studio, which is where Automator is designed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should link against the *Automator* framework, and use a forward class declaration for the button type:

1. Go to your target's *Build Phases* and add **Automator.framework** to the *Link Binary with Libraries* build phase.
2. In your interface/implementation file that declares or references the `AMPathPopUpButton` type, use a forward class declaration instead of trying to import a header file:

   @class AMPathPopUpButton;

Comment: Hi, Brisinda, linking the Automator framework will help eliminate one exception when unarchiving the AMPathPopUpButton control from the nib. But in my situation, I want to call the possible methods that are exposed by this class. Besides, I am using Swift, in which a forward class declaration unfortunately has no use. :)

Comment: The header file is not exposed. But you can set properties of the control using bindings instead (see the bindings inspector for the control). You can also use [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump) to generate the header file and add it to your project. Given that the control exists in Xcode Interface Builder, it *may* not get flagged as using a private API by App Store reviewers if you try to invoke methods on the control directly.